# I am new to python with no previous coding experience. My program is supposed to display the price of a ticket depending on age. Why does it not work?

Tags: python, python-3.7

My code will display ticket price dependent on age. Why is it not working? This is exercise 7-5 from the Python Crash Course book.

```
prompt = "\nEnter Age: "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' when done."
age = ''

while age != 'quit':

    age = input(prompt)
    print(age)
    if age != 'quit':
        if age > '13':
            print(f'You ticket price is $15.00.')
            print(f'Retrieve your ticket(s) below')

        if age <= '13' and age > '2':
            print(f'Your ticket price is $10.00.')
            print(f'Retrieve your ticket(s) below')

        if age < '3':
            print(f'Your ticket price is free')
            print(f'Retrieve your ticket below')

print(f'Thank You Enjoy the show')
```

Comment: Can you define "not working"? Are you seeing any error messages? Does the program run at all? Are you seeing a blank screen? I'm not able to reproduce behavior I personally would consider "not working" in my [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/IdenticalToughContent#main.py)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Quick guess: you compare the input as Strings. That means 31 would be sorted between 3 and 4. Convert the input to int (`int(age)`) and compare to numbers: `if int(age) > 13:`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to cast your input to an int. Input reads everything in as a string.

```
age = int(input(prompt))
```

This would also mean you need to change

```
age != 'quit'
```

After that, you need to make sure you are comparing int's not strings. A string can be greater than or less than another string, but not in the context that you are using them. Change `'13'` to `13` and so forth.

Comment: Strings can be greater (or smaller) than other strings, that's ordering alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

In the if statements change your numbers from `if age < '13':` to `if age < 13:` 
(Change on all if statements) Otherwise 13 is read as a string and cannot be used as an int.

Comment: Sorry this is wrong, Silly me... it will fix your problem if you do it this way: "if int(age) > 13:" This way you "quit" functionality will still work! Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your input value to an integer before using comparators

- lower() means you're converting it to lower chars
- strip() means you're removing spaces surrounding the text

```py
prompt = ''
while prompt.lower().strip() != 'quit':
    prompt = input("Enter your age (enter 'quit' to exit) : ")
    if prompt.lower().strip() != 'quit':
        age = int(prompt) # Converting prompt to an integer
        print(f"Your age : {age}")
        if age > 13:
            print(f'You ticket price is $15.00.')
            print(f'Retrieve your ticket(s) below\n')

        if age <= 13 and age >= 3:
            print(f'Your ticket price is $10.00.')
            print(f'Retrieve your ticket(s) below\n')

        if age < 3:
            print(f'Your ticket price is free')
            print(f'Retrieve your ticket below\n')

print(f'Thank You Enjoy the show')
```

Here is the result :

```
Enter your age (enter 'quit' to exit) : 2
Your age : 2
Your ticket price is free
Retrieve your ticket below

Enter your age (enter 'quit' to exit) : 3
Your age : 3
Your ticket price is $10.00.
Retrieve your ticket(s) below

Enter your age (enter 'quit' to exit) : 13
Your age : 13
Your ticket price is $10.00.
Retrieve your ticket(s) below

Enter your age (enter 'quit' to exit) : 16
Your age : 16
You ticket price is $15.00.
Retrieve your ticket(s) below

Enter your age (enter 'quit' to exit) : QuIt # Caps doesn't matter
Thank You Enjoy the show
```

Answer (score 0):

It will fix your problem if you do it this way: "if int(age) > 13:"(across all if statements) This way you "quit" functionality will still work! Happy coding!!

Comment: You could just edit your other answer to add this, instead of adding a new answer.

Comment: Oh crap, I mustve did it wrong... I thought I did edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this simplification of your code helps:

```
age = int(input("Enter Age: "))
if age > 13:
    print('You ticket price is $15.00.')
    print('Retrieve your ticket(s) below')
if age <= 13 and age > 2:
    print(f'Your ticket price is $10.00.')
    print(f'Retrieve your ticket(s) below')
if age < 3:
    print('Your ticket price is free')
    print('Retrieve your ticket below')
```

Answer (score -3):

I think I have an answer. First, why do you use print(f'')? You can just use print(''). Also, there is no need to type prompt='\nEnter'; you can just type prompt='Enter'!

Comment: Neither of these facts is what is preventing the program from "working" as intended.

Comment: No, the correct solution has been proposed by @ptan9o. The original code attempts to compare two strings and use comparison operators with those.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and python. Thanks to all for the help. I now see the error of my ways with this simple code. I will be glad when I get to the point when I can contribute an answer to a python problem.